# Can Gradle C++ dependencies get set differently for different applications?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, dependencies, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have some applications in the same project that have the same dependencies that are also being built, some of which need them as static and others need them shared. I built a very basic show of this error based off of the answer at https://github.com/gradle/gradle-native/issues/1017 and it's getting practically the same error. It's a basic project with 2 libraries, :1 and :2, and a cpp-application at :app. This spits out the following error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:nativeRuntimeDebug'.
   > Could not resolve project :1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Module 'gradletest:1' has been rejected:
           Cannot select module with conflict on capability 'gradletest:1:unspecified' also provided by [gradletest:1:unspecified(debugSharedRuntimeElements), gradletest:1:unspecified(debugStaticRuntimeElements)]
   > Could not resolve project :1.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :2
      > Module 'gradletest:1' has been rejected:
           Cannot select module with conflict on capability 'gradletest:1:unspecified' also provided by [gradletest:1:unspecified(debugSharedRuntimeElements), gradletest:1:unspecified(debugStaticRuntimeElements)]
```

Here's my sample that I got to break this. I'm pretty sure I followed everything the answer said in github, and have perused the gradle docs for everything I can find that may be relevant. In my current, non-MVP situation I would have an :app2 that would have :1 and :2 linked as shared libraries, so just setting :1 and :2 to be static will not fix the issue unfortunately.

### 1/build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    `cpp-library`
    `cpp-unit-test`
}

library {
    linkage.set(listOf(Linkage.STATIC, Linkage.SHARED))
}
```

### 2/build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    `cpp-library`
    `cpp-unit-test`
}

library {
    linkage.set(listOf(Linkage.STATIC, Linkage.SHARED))
    dependencies {
        implementation(project(":1"))
    }
}
```

### app/build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    `cpp-application`
    `cpp-unit-test`
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":1")) {
        attributes { attribute(Attribute.of("org.gradle.native.linkage", Linkage::class.java), Linkage.STATIC) }
    }
    implementation(project(":2")) {
        attributes { attribute(Attribute.of("org.gradle.native.linkage", Linkage::class.java), Linkage.STATIC) }
    }
}

application {
}
```

This was done on Gradle 5.4.1, and unfortunately it is incredibly hard to get updates so I was unable to test to see if it's the old version that's the problem.